# What is wrong with ${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2} \cdot {12 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}$ as combinations for two pair in poker?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Let's consider two pairs in a 52 cards deck of poker where every person gets five cards.

My idea to approach this problem is to take following steps:

1. First pair

   - There are ${4 \choose 2}$ combinations getting two cards of the same rank
   - There are ${13 \choose 1}$ combinations of having a specific rank out of a suit
2. Second pair

   - There are still ${4 \choose 2}$ combinations to get two cards of the same rank
   - However as one card per suit is gone we only have ${12 \choose 1}$ for each combination out of a suit
3. Any card

   - There are ${4 \choose 1}$ combinations getting one card out of the same rank
   - There are ${11 \choose 1}$ combinations to getting one card out of a suit

This would yield in:

$$P(TP) = \frac{{4 \choose 2}{13 \choose 1} \cdot {4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 1} \cdot {4 \choose 1}{11 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Two_pair) the correct probability would be calculated as:

$$P(TP) = \frac{{13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 1}{11 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

**What is the mistake in my model and how could I think of the one provided in wikipedia?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realize that in your way to select pairs first you are fixing a rank say 1 and then in second part another rank say 2. also the possibility that in first rank was 2 and second rank was 1 is counting different in your way counting but actually its same So for choice of pairs you have to divide it by 2 and then your answer will match automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Your number is twice wikipedia's number.  That is because you counted two Jacks, two kings, as well as two kings,two jacks.  So you counted each hand twice.

Comment: Is it possible to use four binomial coefficient to show this? I am confused that they only use three though these are separate steps.

Comment: The two ranks are picked using the same $13\choose2$ coefficient.

Comment: @bodokaiser  Note that $$\binom{13}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}$$